# Choose vectors that make this problem infeasible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, optimization, vectors

[image]

---

Note:

1. $c$ **is a row vector**. I think the rest are column vectors.
2. $x \ge 0$ means $x_i \ge 0$

---

What I tried:

$$b = [-1 -1], c = -b$$

It seems that both the primal and dual are infeasible.

However, I noticed that we need to have

$$-b_2 \le x_1 - x_2 \le b_1$$

and

$$-c_2 \le y_1 - y_2 \le c_1$$

Must it be then that

$$-b_2 \le b_1, -c_2 \le c_1$$

?

In that case, it doesn't seem like $b = [-1, -1]$ works.

What can I use instead?

---

From Chapter 2 [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ABIU1apSS8r3CbA&id=5EA51B764D593198%212679&cid=5EA51B764D593198).

Comment: one $b_i$ or one $c_i$ is not sufficient. Try $b = (-1, -1)$, $c=(1,1)$.

Comment: @user251257 I'll check tomorrow. Are you sure the dual is infeasible?

Comment: $b=(-1,0)$ will work too, but $b=(-1,1)$ won't. I think you get the idea.

Comment: @user251257 I'm not trusting you. I did not say I will check only if you are unsure. But maybe if you've found a mistake you could save time

Comment: @user251257 why did you delete your other comment?

Comment: it wasn't helpful. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose $$b=[-1,-1], c=-b$$

Both the primal and dual are infeasible.